# Finding points of a scrabble word

Tags: c

So i recently started c language with no prior knowledge of coding or computer science. Wrote this piece of code to find value of a word using scrabble points as below:
1:AEILNORSTU   2:DG   3:BCMP   4:FHVWY   5:K   8:JX   10:QZ.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <ctype.h>
# include <conio.h>
int main (void)
{
  int n=0;
  char ch;
  clrscr();
  printf("Enter the SCRABBLE word\n");
  ch = getchar();
  while(ch!='\n')
  {
    toupper(ch);
    if(ch =='A'||'E'||'I'||'L'||'N'||'O'||'R'||'S'||'T'||'U')
      n=n+1;
    else if (ch =='D'||'G')
      n=n+2;
    else if (ch =='B'||'C'||'M'||'P')
      n=n+3;
    else if (ch =='F'||'H'||'V'||'W'||'Y')
      n=n+4;
    else if (ch =='K')
      n=n+5;
    else if (ch =='J'||'X')
      n=n+8;
    else if (ch =='Q'||'Z')
      n=n+10;

    ch = getchar();
  }
  printf("The value is %d",n);
  return 0;
}
```

So what happens when i run this code is that :
    **Enter the SCRABBLE word**
  eg: *barrier*
    **The value is 7**
though it should be 9 as b carries 3 points as noted above the code,a carries 1,r carriers 1,again r 1 point,i carries 1 point and the last two alphabet are one point each so thats 3+1+1+1+1+1+1=9

Comment: What is a Scrabble word?? You said Scrabble word, but you are giving a character as input.. plz clarify

Comment: Please learn about *indentation*. Also consider using empty lines to divide the code into blocks. It will make the code easier to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: Furthermore, the [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an `int`. It's important when you check for errors or end-of-file (when `getchar` returns `EOF`). Something you really should check for.

Comment: "I'm not getting the correct answer" isn't helpful.

Comment: What are you inputting? What are you getting out? (What is the expected output? Is case suppose to be sensitive? (This only allows uppercase words)

Comment: Use the right type as commented, `char ch;` ==> `int ch;` and another important technique is to *read the man page* of every function you use.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

An expression like `ch =='D'||'G'` is equal to `(ch == 'D')||'G'`.

In other words you first perform the sub-expression `ch == 'D'`. Then you do a logical or using `'G'`. The result will *always* be true since `'G'` is non-zero, and everything non-zero is true in C.

You want `ch == 'D' || ch == 'G'` instead, to check if `ch` is equal to `'D'` or if `ch` is equal to `'G'`.

This is very basic and every [good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would have told you so.

---

In the specific case of the code you show, the very first check will *always* be true because of this, and you will not check any other cases.

Comment: Thanks this seems to have solved my problem.Except another one crept up. It always shows 0 if i input alphabets in lower case. If i input using caps lock the answer is right. Guess some problem in my 'toupper()' ? Thanks again

Comment: @NayanT The [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) function *returns* the new character. It can't modify it in place.

Comment: Ah Thanks again. Will be sure to practicing on my indentation too. ;D

Answer (score -1):

you forgot to get the return value of `toupper`. Also you don't check it 
(according to `man 3 toupper`, the function will return the same char in case of failure)

Then your conditions aren't good:
`if (ch == 'Q' || 'Z')` is different from `if (ch == 'Q' || ch == 'Z')`
The `||` means **if the right or the left condition is true** and in the first case `(ch == 'Q')` is not always true, but `'Z'` is always true.

This means your first condition :

`if(ch =='A'||'E'||'I'||'L'||'N'||'O'||'R'||'S'||'T'||'U')`

**is always true**

Here are littles corrections you can apply, this might work

```
    char         tmp;
    ch = getchar();
    while(ch!='\n')
    {
        //Stocking in a tmp char to check return value
        tmp = ch;

        //Here
        ch = toupper(ch);
        if (ch == tmp)
        {
          //Error
          break;
        }
        {...}
        else if (ch =='Q'|| ch =='Z')
          n += 10;
        ch = getchar();
    }
```

Edit : Correction of return value of `toupper()`;

Comment: Hello thanks . Yes some problem with my toupper. Could you please explain a bit about the if block containing break.is it checking for error.How? Thanks again.

Comment: Hello thanks . Yes some problem with my toupper. Could you please explain a bit about the if block containing break.is it checking for error.How? Thanks again.

Comment: As Drumz said, `toupper()` will return `'c'` if it fails. So you have to check if `ch` is equal to `'c'` to see if there was an error.

Comment: @Drumz You have misread. `toupper` does not return `'c'`. When no conversion is made it returns the input character.

Comment: @stark Okay thanks, my bad

Comment: @NayanT Break is a keyword that "break" the loop (it will stop your while loop even if the condition is true)

Comment: If `ch` already is an upper case character no conversion is done. You shouldn't treat this as an error. Calling `isalpha(ch)` might be more useful to detect errors.

Comment: Or just handle in a default `else` case.

Comment: Ah understood. so that is for checking error.neat trick.